# After switching from PHP 5 to 7 for a local 2.x install, I can't login

Tags: php, login

I have Craft running locally, the latest 2.x branch. When I change the server to run PHP 7 instead of 5.x, the local Craft frontend still works, but I can't login to the backend. It says "Invalid username or password", even after doing the reset password process.

Trying to prep a site for upgrading to Craft 3, but if I can't even get Craft 2.x running on PHP 7... :-/

Comment: Any change you are running PHP 7.2?

Comment: I _was_, but saw the incompatibility note in the docs and so switched to 7.1. No difference—not even via password reset.

Comment: If you have access to the mysql db - enter the following values for the user you are trying to access: -- USERNAME: 'admin' || PASSWORD: '$2a$13$5j8bSRoKQZipjtIg6FXWR.kGRR3UfCL.QeMIt2yTRH1.hCNHLQKtq'; If that doesnt work you will probably have to look at the logs and see what errors are being thrown -- the password phrase to use will be 'password'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that it was a PHP configuration issue.

Under Windows, the paths in `php.ini` need to include a drive letter (eg. `c:\xampp\php7\`). By default they're root-relative (eg. `\xampp\php7`). When I originally installed XAMPP with PHP 5.x, it adjusted the paths automatically. But when I manually copied the PHP 7 folder into XAMPP to set it up for version switching, I overlooked the path discrepancy.

In this case, it was the inability of PHP 7 to set sessions that was causing the odd behavior.